# date.month() inside a map() function

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am trying to create a Grafana dashboard of water consumption per month.
And i decided to use Flux as i need to convert between liters and cubic meters.
So apart from getting the data, filtering, doing the appropriate l/m3 calculation, and calculating a month difference, I have troubles linking up the data with the appropriate month.

So i narrowed it down to: `date.month(t: r._stop)`
Whenever i want to return it from a map function i have the following error:

```
Error: cannot compile polymorphic function @ 16:32-23:2: type variable "t125" is not monomorphic
```

Haven't found anything relative on google, but i noticed i get almost the same error when using `date.weekDay(t: r._stop)`

**I tried creating a proxy function, but the Chronograph just replied with [object Object]**

Here is my code:

```
import "date"
getMonthFromStart = (startTime) => date.month(t: startTime)
data = from(bucket: "default_db")
  |> range(start: -40, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "Vannsensor1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "total")
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"])
dailyData = data
  |> window(every: 1mo)
firstValue = dailyData |> first() |> rename(columns: {_value: "first_value"})
lastValue = dailyData |> last() |> rename(columns: {_value: "last_value"})
joinedData = join(tables: {first: firstValue, last: lastValue}, on: ["_start", "_stop"])

result = joinedData |> map(fn: (r) => {
  dailyUsage = r.last_value - r.first_value
  converted_value = if "m3" == "l" then float(v: dailyUsage) * 100.0 else if "m3" == "m3"    then float(v:dailyUsage) / 10.0 else float(v:dailyUsage)
  monthInt =  date.month(t: r._stop)
  return {_time: r._start, dailyUsage: converted_value , month: monthInt } // Changed from r._time to r._start

})

result |> yield(name: "daily_usage")
```

Version:

```
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.8.6
```